# Does JS import always requires export?

Tags: javascript

I spent a little more time in Python and there, importing from another file just takes a
`from file import functionName` Is export required in Javascript when importing? I would like to split my single file into several different ones as it becomes more and more difficult to read. There should be only one function in each of the additional files. When I tried to import these extra files just by `import {functionName} from './modules/filename.js'` then I was getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './modules/filename.js' does not provide an export named 'functionName'`, but when I added when I wrote export before the function like `export function functionName() {}`, everything works fine. Do I understand correctly that in JS, import always requires export?

Comment: Import what you need to import, export what you need to export. It's perfectly fine for a file to have only exports and no imports - or the other way around with only imports and no exports.

Comment: Yes your JS file is a module and you maybe want to only expose part of it (not the "internal" implementation. In order to communicate you want to expose something in your module you need the export keyword: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Comment: @Arcord All right. Now I understand. Simply importing without exporting in Python is enough, hence my question. I think you can add your comment as an answer. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JS file is a module and you need to specify what will be exposed by this module:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

You could create a library where you do not want to expose all internal methods but only some of them and you can achieve that with the `export` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you use javascript.
In Node JS : https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html
In SPA like React Angulat Vue / modern JS:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export
- https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

If you use the old JavaScript way, then you should probably use multiple `<script/>` import tags in your html

Comment: Basically, the backend of this project work in Django Javascript is used in this project to fetch requests and to create a slightly more 'modern' look, that e.g. a new chat message does not require reloading the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

An `import` requires an `export` somewhere, not necessarily in the same file. You have a module JS file which exports some resources and at the point you use the given module, you import the resources you need. So, if you attempt to `import` some resource, then that resource must be specified by an `export` command in a module file you use.